# .checked=true not working with jquery $ function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, properties

i want to select a checkbox when a button is clicked.

```
<form action="" method="post" id="form2">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkone" value="one" name="one" />
    <input type="button" value="Click me" id="buttonone"/>
</form>
```

when i tried the following, the checkbox was not getting selected

```
$('#buttonone').click(function() {
    $('#checkone').checked=true;
});
```

then i tried:

```
$('#buttonone').click(function() {
    document.getElementById('checkone').checked=true;
});
```

this time the checkbox got selected. why isn't it getting selected with the jquery $ function?

Comment: @illarra - That's not the best way to do it, that's the best way to a jQuery novice to *quickly*, but not *efficiently* solve the problem...also that link doesn't answer the question at all.  He asked *why doesn't `.checked = true` work here*?...I don't see that covered at all, and I doubt you'd find the answer on google in just 10 seconds.

Comment: You are right @Nick Craver, I misunderstood the second part of the question here. I tried to undo my -1 but can't now. The answer from @Anurag makes it clear.

Comment: @illarra - It's edited, releasing your vote now :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try

```
$('#checkone').attr('checked', true);
```

or

```
$('#checkone').get(0).checked = true;
```

or

```
$('#checkone')[0].checked = true; // identical to second example
```

The reason your first code didn't work is because you were trying to set the `checked` property on a jQuery object which will have no visible effect as it only works  on the native DOM object.

By calling `get(0)` or accessing the first item `[0]`, we retrieve the native DOM element and can use it normally as in your second example. Alternatively, set the `checked` attribute using jQuery's `attr` function which should work too.

Comment: @anish - added an explanation, please let me know if it's still unclear, and I'll elaborate further

Comment: @Anurag - thanks a lot. great explanation. does this apply to all properties and methods of javascript?

Comment: +1, but I really don't like the `attr()` version. It's inefficient, more likely to go wrong and perpetuates the confusion over attributes and properties.

Comment: @anish - Yes, there is a big difference between object properties and DOM attributes. jQuery tends to blur the distinction beyond recognition at times. @Tim - lately I've been developing the notion that the whole attributes/properties in DOM is a mess. I mean why not make properties synonymous to attributes. `setAttribute(.., ..)` will update the `property` in most cases, but not vice-versa. Honestly, I think seeing properties as a working copy that doesn't sync back with initial attributes is conceptually wrong from the get go, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: this one worked for me : $('#checkone')[0].checked = true; thank u so much! the first on is setting it to on

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) *for the jQuery object*, like this:

```
$('#buttonone').click(function() {
  $('#checkone').attr('checked', true);
});
```

But it's better to do it the DOM way, like this:

```
$('#buttonone').click(function() {
  $('#checkone')[0].checked = true; //get the DOM element, .checked is on that
});
```

Or, completely without jQuery:

```
document.getElementById('buttonone').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('checkone').checked = true;
};
```

Comment: That second example highlights the issue. jQ newcomers sometimes forget they're working with a jQ object, not a DOM object.

Comment: @jasongetsdown - jQ newcomers sometimes forget they're working with a jQ object, not a DOM object. nice tip.


@Nick Craver - why is $('#checkone')[0].checked = true; more better.

will this make it perform fast?

Comment: @anish-m - Yes, it has significantly better performance than `.attr()`...accessing a DOM property is *always* faster than going *through something else* to access it.

Comment: accessing a DOM property is always faster than going through something else to access it. thanks a lot for the info

Answer (score 1):

None of these answers worked for me because I incorrectly had multiple radios with the same name attributes:

```
<div id="group-one">
  <input type="radio" name="groups" value="1" checked="checked" />
  <input type="radio" name="groups" value="2" />
</div>
<div id="group-two">
  <input type="radio" name="groups" value="1" checked="checked" />
  <input type="radio" name="groups" value="2" />
</div>
```

Javascript won't recognize the checked attribute (obviously).  This was a result of using `include` to add a similar section of HTML multiple times.  Obviously, clicking on a radio button will uncheck the radio toggles with the same name.

Here's a jsfiddle to show that two radio elements can have the attribute `checked` but only the last one is actually checked:

http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/5ecq8/

Again, pretty obvious, but possibly something to watch out for: remove `id` and `name` attributes from files that you intend to include into other files multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#checkone').attr('checked', true);
```

You don't have direct access to DOM object properties because jQuery operates on collections (`$(selector)` is an array). That's why you have functions defined to manipulate the contents of the returned elements.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('#checkone').attr('checked', true);
```

cleary googling for "jquery check a checkbox" was the way to go

Answer (score 0):

Or you could simply do

```
$('#buttonone').click(function() {
    $('#checkone')[0].checked=true;
});
```

It is because ".checked" is not part of jQuery and you are trying to use it on a jQuery object. If you index a jQuery object at [0] you get the raw Javascript object which ".checked" exists on.

More here: http://phrappe.com/javascript/convert-a-jquery-object-to-raw-dom-object/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    $('#buttonone').click(function() {
  $('#checkone').prop('checked', true);
});
```